# Which one is bigger, $\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i$ or $\prod_{i\in I}\kappa_i$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(\kappa_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of cardinals. If $I=\{1, 2\}$ and at least one $\kappa_i$ is infinite and they are all non-empty, then
$$\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i = \prod_{i\in I}\kappa_i.$$
But what if $I$ is a set, which one is bigger:
$$\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i \qquad\text{or}\qquad  \prod_{i\in I}\kappa_i\qquad?$$
I know that if $(\kappa'_i)$ is another family indexed by the same set $I$ and $\kappa_i<\kappa'_i$ for all $i$, then
$$\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i < \prod_{i\in I}\kappa'_i.$$
Does it also hold that
$$\prod_{i\in I}\kappa_i < \prod_{i\in I}\kappa'_i$$
and
$$\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i < \sum_{i\in I}\kappa'_i\qquad ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{\kappa\in\varnothing}\kappa=0$, and $\prod_{\kappa\in\varnothing}\kappa=1$. The first of these is easily derived from the definition of cardinal addition; the second is a bit less obvious, but it also [follows from the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product#Nullary_Cartesian_product).

Your last two inequalities do not hold in general. Let $\kappa_n=\omega_n$ and $\kappa_n'=\omega_{n+1}$ for $n\in\omega$; then $\kappa_n<\kappa_n'$ for all $n\in\omega$, but $\sum_{n\in\omega}\kappa_n=\sum_{n\in\omega}\kappa_n'$ and $\prod_{n\in\omega}\kappa_n=\prod_{n\in\omega}\kappa_n'$.

Comment: @user870623: I was responding to the original version of the question, not to the title: in it you asked *But what if $I$ is an empty set, which one is bigger*.

Comment: As I said, it was a typo. But since it's too late, I opened a new thread asking the original question.